# Modeling database : many small tables or not?

Tags: sql, symfony1, database-design

I have a database with some information which are repeated in some tables.

I want to know if it's interesting to create a table with this information and in the other table, I put only the id.

It's interesting because with this method I haven't got redundance. But I will have to do many joints between my tables in my request, and I'm afraid my request will be more slow.

(I work with symfony if it changes something)

Comment: Can you post examples of the table structures? Where is information repeated?

Comment: I make an application to manage lodgements

I have a table to supply their information (size, rent, ...). I have a foreign key which references a table with the adresses. But in Adresses table, there are keys (district, date of building) which are repeated. So I want to make an other table to supply the repeated key.

But if I want to know where live someone, I have to do four joints... I think the performance will be deteriorated but it's easier for me to encode relation one to many with symfony than one table with all keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the 'information' in question is data that makes up key values. If so, it sounds like the database designer likes to use natural keys and that you prefer to use surrogate keys.

First, these are both merely a question of style. If the natural key values are composite (i.e. involve more than one column) and are included in other columns for data integrity purposes then they are not redundant.

Second, as you have observed, when it comes to performance of surrogate keys you have to weigh the advantage of the more efficient data type (e.g. a single integer column) against the degrading performance of needing to write more JOINs. Note that using surrogates tends to make constraints more troublesome to write e.g. when the required values for a rule is in another table and you SQL product doesn't support subqueries in CHECK constraints then you will need to use a trigger which degrades performance in a high activity environment.

Further consider that performance is not the only consideration e.g. using natural key values will tend to make the data more readable and therefore make the schema easier to maintain because the physical model will reflect the logical model more closely (surrogate keys do not appear in the logical model at all).

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about [Normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). As with so many design aspects it's a trade-off.

Having duplication within the database leads to many problems - for example how to keep those duplicates in step when updating data. So Inserts and Updates may well go more slowly *because* of the duplication. Hence we tend to normalise the database to avoid such duplication. That does lead to more complex queries and possibly some retrieval overhead.

Modern database products tend to do such queries really well if you take a bit of care to have the right indexes in place.

Hence my starting position would be to normalise your data, avoid duplication. Then in a special case perhaps denormalise just pieces where it really becomes essential. For example suppose some part of you database is large, mostly queried rather than updated (eg. historic order information) then perhaps denormalise that bit.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of style.

The answer is, as the seeker has already identified, removal of duplication; Normalisation.  Pull them all into one table, and place a Foreign Key wherever they are used.

Now an Integer FK may be "tidy", but any good, short, fixed length key will do.  Variable length keys are very bad for performance, as the key needs to be unpacked every time the index is searched.

The nature of a Normalised database is more, smaller tables, which is much faster than an Unnormalised data heap, with fewer, larger tables.  Get used to it.

As long as you are Joining on keys, Joins do not cost anything in themselves; ten joins to construct a row do not cost more than five.  The cost is in the table sizes; the indices used; the distribution; the datatypes of the index columns; etc.  Relational dbms are heavily engineered for Normalised databases.

If you need to do lookups of lookups, then that is the way it is.  Just ensure that the tables are Normalised.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't normalise

- How are you going to store values that could potentially be used?
- How are you going to separate "Lookup value" from "Look up value from "LookUpValue" etc
- You'll be slows because you are storing variable length string "Lookup value" across many rows, rather than a nice tidy integer key

This is the more practical points to the other 2 answers...